# Late 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

Raspberry Pi is scheduled for an election [next week, November 6th](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election/3). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates, [as we did earlier this year](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection).  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/late-2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, November 6th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day (as DST ends the prior Sunday), give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- Feel free to take questions from January's if you believe it will be useful to ask again.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Autumn 2017 is long gone (even Spring has now almost finished)! Have I missed something?

Answer (score 8):

Our community is struggling to maintain higher level users over time. Why do you think this is? Do you have any ideas on how that might be fixed?

Answer (score 7):

How would you answer this [question](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/961/senior-member-continuously-mildly-abusive-towards-newbies#comment1775_961) regarding the negative actions of a high reputation user, which was posted to raspberrypi.meta earlier this year? Complete answers should address not only the concerns of the OP, but the behavior in question and the concerns raised in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

Over time there have been a few meta questions related to including other-fruited-pis, such as this one that mentioned banana pi: [Can we ask questions related to banana pi here?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/can-we-ask-questions-related-to-banana-pi-here) With some quick search you can also find similar questions about orange pi.

The historical answer has been that these are *and should be* off-topic here.  Do you support continuing that position?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 3):

How would you respond to a user that attacked you personally for actions you take as a moderator (e.g. deleting or closing their posts).

Answer (score 2):

This site has experimented with "policies" that *arguably* run counter to the process and experience expected from the larger SE universe.  There was some discussion of that, for example, on these two questions:

- [Is converting link-only answers to Community Wiki working?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/is-converting-link-only-answers-to-community-wiki-working)
- [How related to Raspberry Pi must a question be?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/how-related-to-raspberry-pi-must-a-question-be)

What are your thoughts on how closely this site should follow the norms of other SE sites versus developing its own norms that attempt to respect its size and audience.  If you argue for following norms from larger SE sites, how would your respond to the arguments in the meta questions listed that the small size and diverse subject matter encountered on this site require a different approach?  If you argue for "customizing" on this site, how would you choose what fits and mitigate any potential learning curve on high-quality users used to other SE sites who might occasionally contribute here?